# Select and replace a text within a span

Tags: jquery

```
<span id="spanCompare_5_7">
<input type="radio" name="fCompare_5_7" id="fCompare0" value="0">Filter
<input type="radio" name="fCompare_5_7" id="fCompare1" value="1">Compare
</span>
```

How can I replace the "Compare" text with something else?
I have a few of those code blocks and i can not edit it, I just have access via jq.
The span id "spanCompare_5_7" is generic so more of them are on the site and all of them need the same change, so I cant just use this id as a static selector e.g. $("#spanCompare_5_7").
I never know which numbers are going to appear and as I said, I need the change in all of them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the `childNodes` of the element and reset the `nodeValue` of the matching `textNode` descendants:

```
$('span[id^="spanCompare"]').contents().each(function() {
   if ( this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) === 'Compare' ) 
       this.nodeValue = 'whatever';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yyrks4h3/

In case that you want to destructively (*by changing attributes and visible contents*) reset the `innerHTML` of the elements, you can use the `html` method:

```
$('span[id^="spanCompare"]').html(function(_, h) {
   return h.replace(/Compare/g, 'whatever');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this?

```
var html = $('#spanCompare_5_7').html();
html = html.replace("Compare", "");
$('#spanCompare_5_7').html(html);
```

Comment: This will also change names and IDs of the inputs.. also will not work for changing IDs of the outer span..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var spn = $('#spanCompare_5_7');
spn.html(spn.html().replace(/Compare\b/, 'replacement'));
```